# Eloquent - Get related element

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a table called `images` and for each image the users can vote it.
When the user vote the image I add a new row in my `votes` table to register the vote and the `user_id`.

Images:
- Id
- Image name

Votes:
- User_id
- Image_id

Now I need to get all the images ordered by the number of votes, how can I do?

I have added a new method in my Image.php file:

```
  public function votes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany( 'App\Vote' );
    }
```

Should I get all the images and then order it?

I was thinking about:

```
$images = Image::with('votes')->get();
```

Is it the correct way or there is a hidden function in eloquent to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$images = Image::with('votes')->get()->sortByDesc(function($sort)
{
    return $sort->votes->count();
});
```

For pagination please check out the [manual pagination](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/pagination#usage)

Comment: Almost there, I need the result in `DESC` order and I need a pagination. For the DESC order I have added the `second` and `third` parameter to the `sortBy` function, but how about pagination? `->pagination` do not work

Comment: Do you want to get specific page (if so, what is the page size) or create a paginator?

Comment: $images = Image::with('votes')->get()->sortBy(function($sort)
{
    return $sort->votes->count();
}, SORT_REGULAR, true);

Comment: check ^ above to DESC order @ChristianGiupponi

Comment: PawelBieszczad create a paginator.
@GabrielMoretti thanks, I have already solved it

Comment: @ChristianGiupponi can you edit your question to show us how, or maybe accept my answer if it helped?

Comment: I have solved the DESC section, I will try the pagination and will accept it

Comment: Paginator::make has been removed in Laravel-5